# Can files uploaded to Amazon S3 get auto-deleted after few days?

Tags: amazon-s3

Amazon S3 API has added Object Expiration which deleted all the files uploaded **within a folder** after few days.

Is it possible to make the same for each file from the day it was uploaded?

For example when I upload foo.png, after X days, delete that file not all the files within the folder.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your file path is not more than a *prefix* in S3. So, if you have a structure as follows:

```
/  
|  
+--folder1   
    |  
    +--folder2  
    |   
    +--folder3  
    |   |  
    |   +--foo.png  
    |   |  
    |   +--foo2.png  
    |  
    +--bar.png
```

And you want your rule to apply only to foo.png, set it to "folder1/folder3/foo.png" (there will be only one file matching the "entire-name" prefix in your bucket).

But be aware of the limits regarding number of rules. From [Object Expiration docs](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html):

*To set an object’s expiration, you add a lifecycle configuration to your bucket, which describes the lifetime of various objects in your bucket. A lifecycle configuration can have up to 100 rules. Each rule identifies an object prefix and a lifetime for objects that begin with this prefix. The lifetime is the number of days since creation when you want the object removed.*

Comment: Okay I have understood now how it works. Basically I was setting the life cycle for the entire folder instead of a specific prefix. But 100 lifecycles per bucket are pretty much nothing. This is what I am trying to achieve: People will upload files on an S3, and those files will be deleted after X days (Bascially I file uploaded site with a trial option of 7 days). What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: Once you set a lifetime configuration to your bucket, it will be valid for all of its files. This means that, if you have a `files/` folder (or, technically, prefix), and you apply a lifetime policy of 7 days expiration for the `files` prefix on your bucket, each and every file uploaded with this prefix will get deleted 7 days after it was uploaded. This seems to be exactly what you are looking for. You do not need a policy per file. A single one will fit your needs.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work that way. If I apply an expiration to the folder, all the files within the folder will get expiry the same day.

Comment: The prefix I set is *.png for 7 days.

Comment: @jQuerybeast Regarding your first comment, you said exactly what I said :)  
Regarding your second comment, `*.png` is not really a prefix, but a suffix. It won't work.

Comment: The problem is that the files uploaded are expired after X days but everytime on 01:00:00. Thus, if you upload several files in a day, they will all expire after X days, on the same time. That is what was confusing me. By the way, after they expire, will they get deleted or just not able to be accessed? Thanks

Comment: According to the documentation, whenever a set of files expire, they will be queued for deletion (which occurs in an asynchronous manner).

Comment: @Viccari Sorry to bump something that old. if the prefix is set to `folder1/`, I suppose that `folder2`, `folder3` as well as `bar.png` will get deleted by the lifecycle rule? I'm asking because I'm not sure if folders (like folder1, folder2, folder3) are considered s3 files/objects. Thanks!

Comment: @allaire tl;dr: yes, they are going to be deleted. Long answer: prefixes are not considered as S3 objects, but if you specify a life cycle rule with a prefix (which is what `folder1/` is, technically), the rule will apply to all objects containing that prefix. Docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/intro-lifecycle-rules.html#intro-lifecycle-rules-prefix